# How to transform template interpolation with another words to valid expression syntax in js regex?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing template interpolation and words not inside template interpolation. The string can have only those various forms:

```
foo{{bar}}
{{foo}}bar
foo{{bar}}baz
{{foo}}{{bar}}
foo
{{foo}}
{{foo}}bar{{baz}}
```

The text interpolation can appear more than once in the string also the words that are not inside the template interpolation can be more than one.

I want to transform the string by this way: remove the double curly brackets and keep the content. another words are not inside double curly brackets need to wrap with single quote and concat between them using `+`.

The finial results should generate the string to another string like that:

```
foo{{bar}}       // <-- 'foo' + bar
{{foo}}bar       // <-- foo + 'bar'
foo{{bar}}baz    // <-- 'foo' + bar + 'baz'
{{foo}}{{bar}}   // <-- foo + bar
foo              // <-- 'foo'
{{foo}}          // <-- foo
{{foo}}bar{{baz}} //<-- foo + 'bar' + 'baz'
```

So I create a regex `str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, '$1').replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "'$1'")`

The first regex is to remove the double curly brackets.
The second regex is to wrap word(s) with a single quote.

But I got every result wrapped with a single quote. also no contact between them (not sure where to use `+` in which regex)

How can I change the regex so it will fit my requirements?

```
const strs = [
  'foo{{bar}}',
  '{{foo}}bar',
  'foo{{bar}}baz',
  '{{foo}}{{bar}}',
  'foo',
  '{{foo}}',
  '{{foo}}bar{{baz}}'
];

let result = strs.map((s) =>
  s.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, '$1').replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "'$1'")
);

result.forEach((r) => console.log(r));
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yzheom?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing, consider *matching* either bracketed segments or non-bracketed segments. Then you can map each bracketed segment to a substring without brackets, and each non-bracketed segment to its version with single quotes. Finally, join by `+`s.

```js
const strs = [
  'foo{{bar}}',
  '{{foo}}bar',
  'foo{{bar}}baz',
  '{{foo}}{{bar}}',
  'foo',
  '{{foo}}',
  '{{foo}}bar{{baz}}',
];

let result = strs.map((s) =>
  s
    .match(/{{[^}]+}}|[^{]+/g)
    .map(substring =>
      substring.startsWith('{')
        ? substring.slice(2, substring.length - 2)
        : "'" + substring + "'"
    )
    .join(' + ')
);

result.forEach((r) => console.log(r));
```

`{{[^}]+}}|[^{]+` - match either

- `{{[^}]+}}` - Non-`}` characters inside `{{` `}}`, or
- `[^{]+` - One or more non-`{`characters

Comment: I got the idea and it works as expected. but this regex can work if I have this string `fn(foo, 'bar{{baz}}')`? because it wraps the entire string. Does this break your solution?

Comment: What were you expecting to see from `"fn(foo, 'bar{{baz}}')"`?

Comment: `fn(foo, 'bar'+ baz)`. the rules apply here also. the difference is wrapped inside a single quote. I'll add this string to my question.

Comment: That sounds like the tip of a *much* more complicated problem. For that particular example, I suppose you could do something along the lines of matching quoted strings and everything outisde of quotes, then perform the logic above on each segment, then move `{{}}` segments outside the quoted segment if they happen to be on the edge, then join whatever's left of the segment. But that probably wouldn't be robust. A full solution would probably involve writing a lexer for this syntax.

Comment: Make sense. I remove the last string from the question. Thank you.